# Append a value to the latest cell of a column only if it doesn't exist VBA

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel, I need to be able to append a value to the latest cell of a column only if it doesn't exist.

Let's say we need to add a "Test" string to a column of words..

```
COL_WORDS
chair 
car
Bus
Help
```

Comment: Sorry, but your question is really unclear! So you want to add `Test` to `Help`, which is the last cell in the column - but only if `Test` is not already included? Can you provide an example before and after? And also, please show us, what you have done and where you got stuck!

Comment: @Mohamed I think I understand what you are going for, but could you confirm?  See my answer below and let me know if this is right, or not.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You mean, using VBA, you want to append a value to the end of a column if that value doesn't appear in the column (minus the header I would assume)?  If so, this might help:

```
Sub AddIfNotDup(str As String)

    Dim c As Range
    Dim dupFound As Boolean
    Dim lastRow As Long

    dupFound = False
    lastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For Each c In Sheet1.Range("$A$2:$A$" & lastRow)
        Debug.Print c.Value
        If c.Value = str Then
            dupFound = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next c

    If dupFound = False Then
        Cells(lastRow + 1, "A").Value = str
    End If
End Sub

Sub test()
 AddIfNotDup ("mob")
End Sub
```